# Defining priors and marginalizing over priors in pymc

Tags: python, probability, bayesian, pymc, mcmc

I am going through the tutorial about **Monte Carlo Markov Chain process** with **pymc** library. I am also a newbie using **pymc** and try to establish my own MCMC process. I have faced couple of question that I couldn't find proper answer in pymc tutorial:
First: How could we define priors with pymc and then marginalise over the priors in the chain process?

My second question is about `Dirichlet` distribution , how is this distribution related to the prior information in MCMC and how should it be defined?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend following the PyMC user's guide. It explicitly shows you how to specify your model (including priors). With MCMC, you end up getting marginals of all posterior values, so you don't need to know how to marginalize over priors.

The Dirichlet is often used as a prior to multinomial probabilities in Bayesian models. The values of the Dirichlet parameters can be used to encode prior information, typically in terms of a notional number of prior events corresponding to each element of the multinomial. For example, a Dirichlet with a vector of ones as the parameters is just a generalization of a Beta(1,1) prior to multinomial quantities.

Comment: In the case that we have non-parametric probability distribution as prior for one of the parameters, how could we include it? Another question It is still vague for me the application of `Dirichlet` distribution and the situation that it should be used? When you say it is multinomial probability do you mean in one dimension parameter space or it can be in higher dimensions? It is not very intuitive to understand how it works, could you give an example?

Comment: You might be confusing a Dirichlet distribution with a Dirichlet prior process, which are entirely different distributions. The latter is a non-parametric distribution that is based on a stick-breaking (or similar) process. [Here's a notebook containing information on the DPP](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/fonnesbeck/Bios366/blob/master/notebooks/Section5_2-Dirichlet-Processes.ipynb)